# Redirect url does not work with ajax synchronous calls

Tags: jquery, ajax

I am trying to redirect url to signin url whenever my server sends 403 in status code.

```
function processget_sync(data1, url1, handler)
{
    url1=server_url + url1;
    data1=JSON.stringify(data1);
    jQuery.ajax({
         type : "GET",
         url : url1,
         dataType : "json",
         contentType : "application/json; charset=utf-8",
         cache : false,
         async: false,
         statusCode: {
                403:function(){
                    redirectFunction();
                } 
        },
         success : function(ret) {
             handler(ret,null);
         },
         error : function(err) {
             handler(null,err);

         }
    }); 


function redirectFunction(){
    console.log("before redirection")
    window.location.href = "../signin/index.html";
    console.log("after redirection")
  }
```

It both the console.logs are printing, before redirection and after redirection. but redirection is not happening. It works fine if I give **async:true**.

I tried using window.location.assign(), window.location.replace(), location.href and **all other solutions given in similar question threads**. Nothing seems to work in my case

Comment: Take a step back and consider why you would possibly want to use a synchronous call? It's almost never necessary, it causes horrible UX for the user (locks up the browser, which might make them think it has crashed, if the request takes longer than normal), and is even deprecated in some browsers, so you can reasonably expect it to stop working entirely in future. What's your reason for thinking you need a synchronous call? You're implementing callbacks properly for success/error, so it's not some misunderstanding of the async code flow, like I sometimes see.

Comment: This particular function is being used in multiple places in my project, so if I make the call asynchronous now I need to check for all impacts which takes time, so I wanted to know if there is a quick fix with the request being sent synchronously itself

Comment: In that case I would put a test for the specific status code inside the "error" callback for now.

Comment: if(err.status == 403) redirectFunction(); else handler(null,err); I added like this and remove statuscode, still it doesn't work

Comment: can you define "doesn't work"? That doesn't give any clues at all. Any error messages in the console?
 Does the code hit the "error" callback as expected? Is err.status set to what you expect? Does the redirect command get executed (and if so, what happens)?

Answer (score -1):

Initially get your call back value, after that check your condition like this:

```
success: function(data){
  callback(data);
}
if(data == true){
 window.location.href = "../signin/index.html";
}
```

Comment: Yuk. Better to check in the "error" callback. Then when the code is made async later on it won't fall over because of this out-of-scope code.